# How to Use Xpath in variable to pull data?

Tags: javascript, variables, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRmdu.png)

[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3iaF.png)

[Image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfWWm.png)

When I am trying to get data by using JS Path its pulling all these data instead of "Amount" only what should I do ??
Any Idia ?? Or can anyone tell me how to use Xpath in my function instead of JS Path ??

this is my variable:

function(){

var REV=document.querySelector("#content_wrapper > div > div.row.mt-5 > div.col-md-7.mb-5 > div > div.orderRowCost.col-md-5.sordersummary").innerText;

return REV;
}

Answer (score 0):

Here you have several methods to be consider,

Absolute xPath Email Address : ihtml/body/div[2]/form[1]/div[1]/Iabel[1]/input

Password : /html/body/div[2J/form[1]/div[1]/Iabel[2]/input

**Relative xPath**

1. [@AttributeName = 'AttributeValue']

//*[@name='emaill

//*[@type=ltext1

2. ElementType[@AttributeName=AttributeValue

//inpuff@type=itext1

//input[@name='email']

3. [contains(text();XXXX')]

//*[contains(text();Loginl]

4. [text()=`XXXV]

//*[text() ='Login']

Comment: Edited my question please consider my variable.